# Wp7 and Sql Compact

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i am newbie of c# and win phone 7
i create a simple database i read this example
http://f5debug.net/2012/02/26/learn-windows-phone-7-development-in-31-days-day-26-working-with-creating-a-local-database-in-wp7/ 
i open Db in Mainpage

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // short connection string format

    private const string strConnectionString = @"isostore:/ManutenzioneDB.sdf";
    // Costruttore
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

   using (SampleData.EventoDataContext Empdb = new SampleData.EventoDataContext(strConnectionString)) 
   {
       // se il db non esiste creo il db
       if (Empdb.DatabaseExists() == false)
       {
           Empdb.CreateDatabase();
      //     MessageBox.Show("Employee Database Created Successfully!!!");
       }

   }
```

now in Main page i create a button than open an other page

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/InsertData.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

now i don't know can access to Db from InsertData page (InsertData.xaml.cs),

best regads 
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler than you think. :)

```
var db = new SampleData.EventoDataContext();
db.MyTable.InsertOnSubmit(new MyTable() { ... });
db.Submit();
```

1. "MyTable" is the name of the table you defined inside the database.
2. Make sure you define a primary key, or inserting into the table will fail.
3. You will need to initialize your table inside the {...} part.

To get items from the table:

```
foreach (var item in db.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeProp == 1))
{
//…
}
```

This will return all the rows where SomeProp is 1. You can now inspect item to see what the row contains.

Answer (score 0):

Try to study the vici cool stored procedure. It is very very simple to create, add, and retrieve data from any db in WP7 applications

http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home

Comment: thanks for your answer but my problem is: can i ivocke db from other page when i create in mainpaige

Comment: Create a db and make it as public. access that db in another page using any object